# Chrome Extensions mv3: declarativeNetRequest.Rule odd architecture design

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/declarativeNetRequest/Rule)'s the documentation I'm looking at.

I'm setting redirections dynamically and my MVP works wonderfully. The users of my extension are able to set generic redirects from anywhere to anywhere and I'm able to manage them. Something like a generic redirector extension would typically do, but in manifest version 3 (mv3). I'm doing it just like Google wants it, via the declarativeNetRequest permission.

Considered overriding the window.fetch() to do them, but it looks like Chrome allows extensions to redirect .js files with no issues. Despite what the documentation sounds like: ["The redirect url. Redirects to JavaScript urls are not allowed."](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/declarativeNetRequest) Apparently they meant `javascript:` urls, which turns out to be a common misconception.

What I'm struggling with is the seemingly awkward way the rule structure is implemented in. Or maybe I'm missing something.

When users set redirections via my extension's popup UI, I set them like so:

```
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [],
    addRules: newRules
  });
```

That newRules is an array of rule objects. A typical rule looks like so:

```
{
  'id': counter,
  'priority': 1,
  'action': {
    'type': 'redirect',
    'redirect': {
      url: redirect.to
    }
  },
  'condition': {
    'urlFilter': redirect.from,
    'resourceTypes': [
      'script'
    ]
  }
};
```

I've stumbled upon a few things. That id is mandatory and it has to uniquely identify the rule. And the API seemingly misses the functionality to set the id on it's own. I have to supply it. So every time I want to add a new rule, I can't just add it. I have to get all the rules asyncly, then in a callback of that getter, I have to analyze all existing rules (of which there can theoretically be thousands), find the id that hasn't been used yet (or make sure your random id is not used yet) and then add a rule with that id.

Am I missing something? Is it really how they expect us to work with it? I'm definitely not seeing the full scope of this API's intended use, but it's still odd to me that the id is a mandatory field in the sense that they don't set it when it's not set, judging from the documentation. Is there a good reason I might want to set the id manually and not delegate it to the API?

Another oddity that I noticed is that I can't seem to find a place in that rule object where I can store additional info. I tried to, but the API returns an error if it encounters undocumented fields in there. I want to show the user all the rules they've made with dates they made the rules on. To do that without storing the dates in the rule, I have to use the storage api in parallel effectively duplicating the effort of setting, updating and deleting rules. Which is fine. It's doable. But it feels very unnecessary. Almost kinda defeats the purpose of having the API, especially considering how simple it is in mv2.

At this point I'm thinking about keeping all the redirect info in my sync storage and use it to display them in the UI and then every time there's an addition, removal or update of a rule, I dump all existing rules from the `declarativeNetRequest` api, then `.map()` my stored array of rules to what the `declarativeNetRequest` wants and shove them into it. Maybe I'll optimize the  update and delete to be more efficient, but seems like addition of a new rule will be just that.

Comment: The API is designed this way. It's unclear why these obstacles are problematic in a practical sense (other than being inconvenient), so maybe you should show the code or provide more info.

Comment: why does adding a rule have to have the complexity of N on my side? It's much easier for the API to consume that complexity and deal with it than for us to do that.

Comment: Well, you can ask those who designed the API, while here the question in its current form is off-topic as the only answers would be opinions not based on fact. To make it practically answerable you can show your current code and performance measurements, so that we could see if it's indeed problematic and if a better solution exists or might exist theoretically in case the API is improved.

Comment: There's one suggestion I can make right away though: DNR rules are stored in a packed (indexed) form, which is much smaller than its serialized form, so you shouldn't store the rules in storage entirely, just the metadata. Also beware of the limits in chrome.storage.sync for individual value (8k) and the entire storage (100k), as well as number of items. Might want to use CompressionStream + FileReader.readAsDataURL.

Comment: Yeah, my extension won't need more than a few tens of rules, so I'm perfectly fine complexion-wise or storage-wise. I'm just surprised by the seeming awkwardness of the API and thought someone had a good reasoning for it being designed like so. Even if just theoretically.

Comment: You probably think a lot of thought was put into it, but there's no indication this is the case. All the available evidence suggests that DNR was created for exactly one purpose: to process AdBlock-compatible filters like EasyList with some small tweaks added on top.